# How to put a number in data + time in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

so I have numeric values ​​in a .log file that represent a date + time like "day / month / year hour: minutes: seconds"
But by placing a number like this for example "1490569200,0" in an excel cell and converting the cell as time and even after customizing it to the format appears "############### "
How can I solve this?
I want to convert this number to a date and time

Comment: Your number is obviously wrong. `Now()` (in a cell) will return something like `43905.5367677083` Your number looks to exceed excel limits... Try using a reasonable number and your "problem" will not exist, anymore...

Comment: I already realized that if you take the 1490 to the number it gives me a date + time but the problem is that the date is not correct
You should give the date
27/03/2017 is the time but don't show me this value: 31/05/3458 00:00:00

Comment: how can i solve this?

Comment: 27/3/2017 is day number 42821. This is a day count since Jan 1, 1900. Decimals indicate the time. I divided 1490569200,0 by 24, 1440 and (1440 * 60) and got no usable date. So, unless you can lift the secret of what "1490569200,0" stands for it should remain impossible to decode it into a date and time. Perhaps the final ",0" gives a pointer. Does this number come from a system where the commas stands for a decimal point?

Comment: You only must analize why your your .log file wrongly calculate that 'time'. And correct it. Nobody can help you on this issue. Except the case of that .log file it is also produced by VBA and you will post here that specific code...

Comment: This number was displayed by a counter for a .log file and shows data and hours in a row in that format and I know what day should correspond to 03/27/2017 because it is the file for that day that I am working on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date/time code appears to be a UNIX time code.  It is the number of seconds elapsed from 1/1/1970.  Placing your large value in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=ROUND(DATEVALUE("1/1/1970")+A1/(60*60*24),0)
```

Then format **B1** as *d/m/yyyy*:

[image]

Comment: ... one small shift in precondition, one giant leap for conclusion :+)